# Same .NET code files, different web sites/domains in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis

ASP.NET - IIS 6 - we currently have a public-facing site that has a domain mapped against it. We are going to add a new web site in IIS 6, with its own IP, its own SSL cert, and its own domain name on the same server as the original web site/domain.

Let's say I want c:\inetpub\wwwroot\example to be be served up to the two different sites, where each of the following URLs would load the same .NET code.

```
https://www.domainA.com/example
https://www.domainB.com
```

...I'm trying to not splinter my code, but I'm not sure if there are pitfalls with the above approach. Will that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  I have had two separate sites / virtual directories pointing to the same physical directory on the server with one set of code.